# Writing a parser with can use asyncio.StreamReader.readexactly (async), io.BytesIO.read (sync) or any other similar function

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am currently writing a parser for data frames (of varying length), which are received over a streaming connection (in my case serial over TCP). I want the parser to be as universally usable as possible (as others might want to use other read methods), which brings me to my problem.

The function reads the data piece by piece like this (simplified, the original function has ~50 lines of code):

```
async read_frame(reader: StreamReader) -> dict:
    header = reader.readexactly(2)
    start, length = struct.unpack(header, "BB")
    if start == 0x68:
        data = await reader.readexactly(length)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Unexpected start byte")
    
    checksum = await reader.readexactly(1)
    # check data integrity
    # do something with the data chunk
    return parsed_data
```

`reader.readexactly` is the only asynchronous part of the function.

I could simply copy the code to make a synchronous version of the function, however this would result in a lot of duplicated code and thus be error prone. What I would like to have (which seems to not exist) a function/decorator which produces a synchronous version if fed with a synchronous read function and an asynchronous function when fed with a asynchronous read function.

I very grateful for any hints towards an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to wrap the synchronous function if needed like this (untested):

```
from inspect import iscoroutinefunction

async def ensure_co(readfunc):
    if iscoroutinefunction(readfunc):
        return readfunc
    else:
        async def c(*args, **kwargs):
            return readfunc(*args, **kwargs)
        return c
        
async def read_frame(reader):
    if isinstance(reader, StreamReader):
        read = ensure_co(reader.readexactly)
    else:
        read = ensure_co(reader.read)
    
    
    header = await read(2)
    ...
```